# Fading UISegmentedControl colours like Apple Music

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I noticed on the new Apple Music app that if you go to My Music, there is a `UISegmentedControl` that fades the background and text colour of the selected index as you scroll between Library and Playlists. How can I create the same effect? At the moment I have the same setup with a `UIPageViewController` and a `UISegmentedControl` that changes the selected index on scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I can think of is to have another instance of UISegmentedControl with the same configuration as overlaid dummy just to be used as transition effect. This dummy should either be hidden or not on the view when not transitioning.

Prior to transit to another selected index, unhide the dummy with destination index and start with alpha = 0.

Proportional to the scroll transition, adjust the dummy alpha accordingly. On complete transition, set the real instance with the destination index and remove the dummy from superview or hide it.

This should do the trick I think.